# How to take values from several tables in that exacly situation in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1 (game1):

```
Table: game1
id | score | user
 1 |   7   | john
 2 |   3   | alex
 3 |   21  | annie
 4 |   12  | max
```

Table 2 (game2):

```
Table: game2
id | score | user
 1 |   12  | john
 2 |   50  | alex
 3 |   2   | annie
 4 |   9   | max
```

I want to take highscore values from every table game to get something like this:

```
game1 | game2
  21  |  50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use subqueries:

```
select (select max(score) from game1) as game1,
       (select max(score) from game2) as game2
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff using "subquery in the select portion of a query" ? Never thought I'd see the day..

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;

```
select 
(select max(score) from Table1) as Table1,
(select max(score) from Table2) as Table2
```

Answer (score 1):

Result sets that extend horizontally do so by use of the JOIN keyword, vertically by use of the UNION keyword. You say you want horizontal so this will be a join. There's no need to have any join conditions if you reduce each table to one row before you join, and a join without an ON is a CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM
(select max(score) as game1 from game1) a
CROSS JOIN
(select max(score) as game2 from game2) b
```

And so on, you can keep cross joining any number of score tables, only one row will ever result

If you want to retrieve the name of who scored these scores in each game, it makes things rather more complex but not impossible:

```
SELECT * FROM
(select score as game1score, playername as game1winner from game1 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1) a
CROSS JOIN
(select score as game2score, playername as game2winner from game2 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1) b
```

Hopefully you won't get two people scoring the same, because this only picks one of them. Getting a single row result set when there's a tie is a headache

Comment: What "a" and "b" do in that query?

Comment: They provide an alias to the subquery. Some databases don't care if you don't name certain subqueries (oracle), others do (sqlserver). The databases that don't care won't object to an alias being provided, but databases that do care will give a compile error if the subquery isn't named; it's hence safest (and saves having to remember) to just name all subqueries. I could have written `(select ... ) as a` but generally people only use as to alias a column, not a table or subquery

Comment: ps; I've added a bit to show you how to extend the query in case you want more than just the highest score (i.e. You want to know who scored it too). LIMIT is a funny thing in MySQL, there are certain situations where it's not allowed. Thankfully this isn't one of them

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, you can probably use DUAL also in the from clause:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(score) FROM game1) AS game1,
       (SELECT MIN(score) FROM game2) AS game2
FROM DUAL;
```